# Using Sourcegear Vault with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, version-control, sourcegear-vault

We use Sourcegear Vault Standard (version 5.something) for our source control. I need to be able to access the repository on Mac OS, so it seemed like the easiest way to do that was to run Eclipse with the Vault plug-in.

However, there doesn't seem to be a "Guide to using Sourcegear Vault with Eclipse" anywhere, not even on the Sourcegear web site. Does this exist, and if so where can I find it?

Also, I can't seem to find out how to simply see a list of files in the project with eclipse. Is there any way to do this? I can check out all modified files, but I don't always want to check them all out, just one or two.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: download link:

Vault Plug-in for Eclipse:

http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/download-plugin.html

Answer (score 2):

There's an official SourceGear "getting started" how-to here: http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/documentation/eclipsegettingstarted/